# Arduino Nano cannot upload sketch

Tags: arduino, arduino-nano

I have tested a circuit with an arduino nano. Afterwards I created a pcb with the ATMega328 on it and with the exactly same circuit.
If I try to upload my sketch now I get this Error msg.
Thank you for your help in advance.

`
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Nano, ATmega328P (Old Bootloader)"

Sketch uses 9704 bytes (31%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30720 bytes.

Global variables use 390 bytes (19%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1658 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM7 -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\loren\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_829064/slave_test_with_arduino.ino.hex:i

avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619

```
     Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/

     Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch



     System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"



     Using Port                    : COM7

     Using Programmer              : arduino

     Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
```

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x55

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x55

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x55

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x55

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x55

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x55

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x55

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x55

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x55

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x55

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
`

Comment: which bootloader is on the ATmega328P?

Comment: How do I find out?, I tried it with the old bootloader too if that matters.

Comment: well you are the guy who put it onto the ATmega328P so you shoudl know right? if not you probably don't have the Arduino bootloader on the MCU which would explain your problems uploading a sketch.  Read https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/Bootloader?from=Tutorial.Bootloader  the bootloader is basically what makes an Arduino out of a ATmega

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, this should work.

**Remove connections to the board pins, especially the `0 (RX)` and `1 (TX)` digital pins while uploading.**

The above thing worked for me, after uploading again make connections to those pins.

If this is not helpful check the following :-

**1. Check your board and port selections :-** In the top menu bar, make sure the correct board is selected in Tools > Board, and that you’ve selected the right port in Tools > Port. Try disconnecting and reconnecting your board if you’re unsure which port is being used (close and reopen the Port menu to refresh the list). For more information, see Select the right port and board.

**2. Check your sketch for errors :-** Click the Verify button Verify button to compile your sketch without uploading it. If you still get an error, see Compilation errors when uploading.

**3. Check your connections :-** Your board needs to be connected with a data USB cable (charge-only cables will not work). Make sure the cable is fully inserted in the port on each end. Try a different USB cable, and avoid hubs and other adapters if possible. Remove connections to the board pins, especially the 0 (RX) and 1 (TX) digital pins.

For further help refer this
https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/4403365313810-Errors-when-uploading-a-sketch